# Distribution inequality

Tags: probability

I want to prove that if $Y\geqslant 0$ and $EY^2<\infty$, then
$$\mathbf{P}(Y>0)\geqslant \frac{(EY)^2}{EY^2}.$$

I've got so far:
$$DX\geqslant 0,$$
$$EY^2-(EY)^2\geqslant 0$$
We know that $\mathbf{P}(Y< 0)=0$, therefore
$$EY^2-(EY)^2\geqslant \mathbf{P}(Y< 0),$$
$$EY^2-(EY)^2\geqslant EY^2\mathbf{P}(Y< 0).$$
$$EY^2-EY^2\mathbf{P}(Y< 0)\geqslant (EY)^2,$$
$$EY^2(1-\mathbf{P}(Y< 0))\geqslant (EY)^2,$$
$$EY^2\mathbf{P}(Y\geqslant 0)\geqslant (EY)^2,$$
$$\mathbf{P}(Y\geqslant 0)\geqslant \frac{(EY)^2}{EY^2}.$$
I don't know how to deal with $\mathbf{P}(Y=0)$. Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe that $Y=Y\cdot 1_{\{Y>0\}}$, and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.